# GWT: add Widget to new Window browser

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, jsni

I have a GWT application with links to services by clicking on a link,a blank window is opened which I have to insert a progressBar (widget I created myself) until generation of service return url so I redirect the new  window to that url.
So my question how to inject a new widget into new window browser.
Note: I used JSNI  to open new window this way
win =$wnd.open = $ (url, name, "");
and when service is generated i use this:wnd.location = url;

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance for your helps

Answer (score 0):

In your case `win` is a handler to new window [DOM's `window` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window).

Try creating a new GWT module that contains only your progressbar and inject it in the new window via `window.document`:

```
win.document.write("<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" 
    src="gwtmodule/gwtmodule.nocache.js"</script>");
```